# Background is blocking my login form to write ID Password

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please use the below code in notepad and save as html to see output. There is a login form and an animated background. After adding the background, I am not able to click the username box and not able to write anything in that. Tried changing position in CSS. But it is not happening.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> <style type="text/css"> html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: rgb(2, 0, 36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%, rgba(149, 199, 20, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 212, 255, 1) 96%);
}

.myForm {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
    padding: 15px !important;
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    color: white;
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

input {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 0 15px 15px 0 !important;
}

input:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}

.br-15 {
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px !important;
}

.submit_btn {
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    background-color: #95c714 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}

#particles-js {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 1;
}

</style> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css"> <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous"> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <dvi class="container h-200"> <div class="d-flex justify-content-center"> <div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm"> <div class="card-header"> <center> <h5>Admin Portal</h5> </center> </div> <form> <div class="card-body"> <div id="dynamic_container"> <div class="input-group"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span> </div> <input type="text" placeholder="Login ID" class="form-control"/> </div> <div class="input-group mt-3"> <div class="input-group-prepend"> <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span> </div> <input type="password" placeholder="Login Password" class="form-control"/> </div> </div> </div> <div class="card-footer"><center> <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg submit_btn"> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> LOGIN</button></center> </div> </form> </div> </div> </dvi> <div id="particles-js"></div> <script type="text/javascript"> $.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js", function() {
    particlesJS('particles-js', {
        "particles": {
            "number": {
                "value": 80, "density": {
                    "enable": true, "value_area": 800
                }
            }
            , "color": {
                "value": "#ffffff"
            }
            , "shape": {
                "type": "circle", "stroke": {
                    "width": 0, "color": "#000000"
                }
                , "polygon": {
                    "nb_sides": 6
                }
                , "image": {
                    "width": 100, "height": 100
                }
            }
            , "opacity": {
                "value": 0.5, "random": false, "anim": {
                    "enable": false, "speed": 1, "opacity_min": 0.1, "sync": false
                }
            }
            , "size": {
                "value": 5, "random": true, "anim": {
                    "enable": false, "speed": 40, "size_min": 0.1, "sync": false
                }
            }
            , "line_linked": {
                "enable": true, "distance": 150, "color": "#ffffff", "opacity": 0.4, "width": 1
            }
            , "move": {
                "enable": true, "speed": 6, "direction": "none", "random": false, "straight": false, "out_mode": "out", "attract": {
                    "enable": false, "rotateX": 600, "rotateY": 1200
                }
            }
        }
        , "interactivity": {
            "detect_on": "canvas", "events": {
                "onhover": {
                    "enable": true, "mode": "repulse"
                }
                , "onclick": {
                    "enable": true, "mode": "push"
                }
                , "resize": true
            }
            , "modes": {
                "grab": {
                    "distance": 400, "line_linked": {
                        "opacity": 1
                    }
                }
                , "bubble": {
                    "distance": 400, "size": 40, "duration": 2, "opacity": 8, "speed": 3
                }
                , "repulse": {
                    "distance": 200
                }
                , "push": {
                    "particles_nb": 4
                }
                , "remove": {
                    "particles_nb": 2
                }
            }
        }
        , "retina_detect": true, "config_demo": {
            "hide_card": false, "background_color": "#b61924", "background_image": "", "background_position": "50% 50%", "background_repeat": "no-repeat", "background_size": "cover"
        }
    }
    );
}

);
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please check [ask] and try to follow the guidelines there on how to ask a good and answerable question. Please also consult [mre] on which parts of your code to attach. Also please note: Javascript is not java (fixed that last part for you). You should know which technologies and languages you are using.

Comment: Try replacing `<div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm" style="z-index: 999999;">` add z-index and check

Comment: Mridul Sir. It worked. thank you so much.

Comment: try moving the "background" as the first body element

Comment: You don't have to set 99999... This big number, It only needs to be bigger than `#particles-js { z-index:1 }`.

Comment: You can checkout this sample https://codepen.io/matteobruni/pen/xxGXELa

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in tag name replace `dvi` to `div` line 72.

Just change `z-index` in `#particles-js` to 0 and add class:

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the style:

```
.card  {
     z-index: 33;
}
```

because the input is being rendered behind the canvas.

```css
.card 
{
 z-index: 33;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Admin</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
            html,body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background: rgb(2,0,36);
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(149,199,20,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 96%);

        }

   .myForm{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    padding: 15px !important;
   border-radius: 15px !important;
   color: white;
   position: fixed;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   }

   input{
    position: fixed;
    border-radius:0 15px 15px 0 !important;

   }
   input:focus{
       outline: none;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        border:1px solid #ccc !important;


   }

   .br-15{
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px !important;
   }

   .submit_btn{
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    background-color: #95c714 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
   }
   #particles-js{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    z-index:1;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animated Dynamic Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <dvi class="container h-200">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <center>

                <h5>Admin Portal</h5>
                </center>
            </div>
            <form>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="dynamic_container">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Login ID" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mt-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Login Password" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"><center>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg submit_btn">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> LOGIN</button></center>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </dvi>
    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js", function(){
    particlesJS('particles-js',
      {
        "particles": {
          "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
              "enable": true,
              "value_area": 800
            }
          },
          "color": {
            "value": "#ffffff"
          },
          "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
              "width": 0,
              "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
              "nb_sides": 6
            },
            "image": {
              "width": 100,
              "height": 100
            }
          },
          "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 1,
              "opacity_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 5,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 40,
              "size_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
          },
          "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 6,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "attract": {
              "enable": false,
              "rotateX": 600,
              "rotateY": 1200
            }
          }
        },
        "interactivity": {
          "detect_on": "canvas",
          "events": {
            "onhover": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
          },
          "modes": {
            "grab": {
              "distance": 400,
              "line_linked": {
                "opacity": 1
              }
            },
            "bubble": {
              "distance": 400,
              "size": 40,
              "duration": 2,
              "opacity": 8,
              "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
              "distance": 200
            },
            "push": {
              "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
              "particles_nb": 2
            }
          }
        },
        "retina_detect": true,
        "config_demo": {
          "hide_card": false,
          "background_color": "#b61924",
          "background_image": "",
          "background_position": "50% 50%",
          "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
          "background_size": "cover"
        }
      }
    );

});






</script>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
        <div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm" >
```

with this line

```
<div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm" style="z-index: 999999;">
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your HTML code on my browser and have fixed your problem by just adding a few lines of CSS in style tag. The problem was of z-index

```
.d-flex.justify-content-center {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

You can add this css in your style tag and your problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

No need to manage z-index. Just remove the `z-index:1` in `#particles-js` css and move the whole `<dvi>` block below `<div id="particles-js"></div>`

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
    <title>Admin</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
            html,body{
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background: rgb(2,0,36);
            background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(149,199,20,1) 0%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 96%);

        }

   .myForm{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5) !important;
    padding: 15px !important;
   border-radius: 15px !important;
   color: white;
   position: fixed;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   }

   input{
    position: fixed;
    border-radius:0 15px 15px 0 !important;

   }
   input:focus{
       outline: none;
        box-shadow:none !important;
        border:1px solid #ccc !important;


   }

   .br-15{
    border-radius: 15px 0 0 15px !important;
   }

   .submit_btn{
    border-radius: 15px !important;
    background-color: #95c714 !important;
    border: 0 !important;
   }
   #particles-js{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}
    </style>

</head>
<body>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Animated Dynamic Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="particles-js"></div>
    <dvi class="container h-200">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="card mt-5 col-md-4 animated bounceInDown myForm">
            <div class="card-header">
                <center>

                <h5>Admin Portal</h5>
                </center>
            </div>
            <form>
            <div class="card-body">
                    <div id="dynamic_container">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Login ID" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group mt-3">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <span class="input-group-text br-15"><i class="fas fa-key"></i></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Login Password" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>

                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer"><center>
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg submit_btn">
                <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right"></i> LOGIN</button></center>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    </dvi>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$.getScript("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js", function(){
    particlesJS('particles-js',
      {
        "particles": {
          "number": {
            "value": 80,
            "density": {
              "enable": true,
              "value_area": 800
            }
          },
          "color": {
            "value": "#ffffff"
          },
          "shape": {
            "type": "circle",
            "stroke": {
              "width": 0,
              "color": "#000000"
            },
            "polygon": {
              "nb_sides": 6
            },
            "image": {
              "width": 100,
              "height": 100
            }
          },
          "opacity": {
            "value": 0.5,
            "random": false,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 1,
              "opacity_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "size": {
            "value": 5,
            "random": true,
            "anim": {
              "enable": false,
              "speed": 40,
              "size_min": 0.1,
              "sync": false
            }
          },
          "line_linked": {
            "enable": true,
            "distance": 150,
            "color": "#ffffff",
            "opacity": 0.4,
            "width": 1
          },
          "move": {
            "enable": true,
            "speed": 6,
            "direction": "none",
            "random": false,
            "straight": false,
            "out_mode": "out",
            "attract": {
              "enable": false,
              "rotateX": 600,
              "rotateY": 1200
            }
          }
        },
        "interactivity": {
          "detect_on": "canvas",
          "events": {
            "onhover": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "repulse"
            },
            "onclick": {
              "enable": true,
              "mode": "push"
            },
            "resize": true
          },
          "modes": {
            "grab": {
              "distance": 400,
              "line_linked": {
                "opacity": 1
              }
            },
            "bubble": {
              "distance": 400,
              "size": 40,
              "duration": 2,
              "opacity": 8,
              "speed": 3
            },
            "repulse": {
              "distance": 200
            },
            "push": {
              "particles_nb": 4
            },
            "remove": {
              "particles_nb": 2
            }
          }
        },
        "retina_detect": true,
        "config_demo": {
          "hide_card": false,
          "background_color": "#b61924",
          "background_image": "",
          "background_position": "50% 50%",
          "background_repeat": "no-repeat",
          "background_size": "cover"
        }
      }
    );

});






</script>
</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```